# How to get readable exception thrown by netsuite suitescript 2.0 using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Whenever get exceptions from netsuite suitescript 2.0 (restlet),

able to get readable exception as response like shown below, while suitescript hit from postman,

400 Bad Request

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UNIQUE_CUST_ID_REQD",
    "message": "{\"type\":\"error.SuiteScriptError\",\"name\":\"UNIQUE_CUST_ID_REQD\",\"message\":\"A customer record with this ID already exists. You must enter a unique customer ID for each record you create. To correct this record, click <a href=javascript:history.go(-1);;>back</a> and enter a new customer ID in the Customer field. Then, click Submit.\",\"stack\":[\"createError(N/error)\",\"formatAndThrowException(/SuiteScripts/ns_script.js:633)\",\"createObject(/SuiteScripts/ns_script.js:523)\",\"saveObject(/SuiteScripts/ns_script.js:552)\",\"post(/SuiteScripts/ns_script.js:503)\",\"createError(N/error)\"],\"cause\":{\"name\":\"UNIQUE_CUST_ID_REQD\",\"message\":\"A customer record with this ID already exists. You must enter a unique customer ID for each record you create. To correct this record, click <a href=javascript:history.go(-1);;>back</a> and enter a new customer ID in the Customer field. Then, click Submit.\"},\"id\":\"\",\"notifyOff\":false,\"userFacing\":true}"
  }
}
```

But when made same request to suitescript from spring boot, got unreadable characters as response like shown in below screenshot,

[unreadable characters screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pyil.png)

request headers used in spring boot to call restlet,

```
[
Accept:"application/json", 
Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
Authorization:"OAuth realm="<ORGANIZATION_ID>",
oauth_consumer_key="<CONSUMER_KEY>",
oauth_token="<TOKEN>",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
oauth_timestamp="<TIMESTAMP>",
oauth_nonce="<NONCE_VALUE>",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="<OAUTH_SIGNATURE>",
Content-Length:"779"
]
```

why i can't able to get readable exception information while request made from spring boot ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s been ages since I worked with Spring but Java in general starts up with a default char set that it determines at run time. Search for references to charsets and make sure yours is UTF8